# C# Using VLC Wrapper to stream from IP Camera

Tags: c#, libvlc, ip-camera, libvlcsharp

I am trying to construct a user interface to capture video from an IP Camera (Specifically an Onvif Device). I have constructed appropriate clients and binding elements. I am able to get the URI setup. I cannot however figure out how to use the VLC Wrapper to stream the video. I've imported the references/libraries using Nuget. I am able to add the VLC Active X plugin object to the windows forms.

Past this I am struggling to figure out how to set up. I know i need to set up a call to the player and past it my constructed Uri (with the port, host, and scheme), and username and password.

I'm not sure which steps to take next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActiveX control is deprecated. You should be using a .NET binding like LibVLCSharp.

The [README](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp) will guide you through the steps of creating your first app.

Basic steps are:

- Install LibVLC through nuget
- Install LibVLCSharp through NuGet
- Call Core.Initialize()
- Create your VideoView and your MediaPlayer

Comment: Thank you! I am still having issues but this has gotten me much closer.